# XMLQuery to get data

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following SQL :

```
with q1 (Tdata) as (
  SELECT XMLtype(transportdata, nls_charset_id('AL32UTF8')) 
  from bph_owner.paymentinterchange pint 
where --PINT.INCOMING = 'T' and
PINT.TRANSPORTTIME >= to_date('2022-08-10', 'yyyy-mm-dd') 
and pint.fileformat = 'pain.001.001.03'
)
--select XMLQuery('//*:GrpHdr/*:InitgPty/Nm/text()'
select tdata, XMLQuery('//*:GrpHdr/*:CtrlSum/text()'
  passing Tdata
  returning content).getstringval()
  ,
  XMLQuery('//*:GrpHdr/*:MsgId/text()'
  passing Tdata
  returning content).getstringval()
from q1;
```

This works but for the InitgPty/Nm/ it doesn't - anybody know how I can extract this information?
Please be gentle as I don't work with XML much.
Thanks

Comment: Some sample data and expected results would be useful. You might just need to wildcard the `Nm` node too, as `'//*:GrpHdr/*:InitgPty/*:Nm/text()'` - though using the proper namespaces and full paths would probably be better.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Many thanks, Alex. That *:Nm has worked 
What/how do I use the namespace/path? 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?><Document xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.001.001.03" xmlns:xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

Comment: @Peterwarren - I looked back at your previous questions and one of those - in which I mentioned wildcards - was about extracting the namespace from the XML, which implied you wouldn't know it in advance; if so then wildcarding is probably still going to be simpler. There also seemed to be some variation in the path down to `GrpHdr`. So what you're doing is probably OK.

Answer (score 0):

Based on sample data from a previous question and other relating to this XML schema, it appears you just need to wildcard the namespace for `Nm` node, as well as its parents:

```
'//*:GrpHdr/*:InitgPty/*:Nm/text()'
```

so the query could become:

```
with q1 (Tdata) as (
  SELECT XMLtype(transportdata, nls_charset_id('AL32UTF8')) 
  from paymentinterchange pint 
where --PINT.INCOMING = 'T' and
PINT.TRANSPORTTIME >= to_date('2022-08-10', 'yyyy-mm-dd') 
and pint.fileformat = 'pain.001.001.03'
)
select
  XMLQuery('//*:GrpHdr/*:InitgPty/*:Nm/text()'
  passing Tdata
  returning content).getstringval() as nm
  ,
  XMLQuery('//*:GrpHdr/*:CtrlSum/text()'
  passing Tdata
  returning content).getstringval() as ctrlsum
  ,
  XMLQuery('//*:GrpHdr/*:MsgId/text()'
  passing Tdata
  returning content).getstringval() as msgig
from q1;
```

But if you're pulling multiple values out of the same document then it's simpler to use XMLTable rather than multiple XMLQuery calls:

```
select x.nm, x.ctrlsum, x.msgid
from paymentinterchange pint
cross apply XMLTable(
  '//*:GrpHdr'
  passing XMLtype(pint.transportdata, nls_charset_id('AL32UTF8'))
  columns nm varchar2(50) path '*:InitgPty/*:Nm',
    ctrlsum number path '*:CtrlSum',
    msgid varchar2(50) path '*:MsgId'
) x
where pint.transporttime >= date '2022-08-10'
and pint.fileformat = 'pain.001.001.03';
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=f488d00a97c71fe809ccd8b17998404f) with data adapted from a previous question.

---

Before Oracle 12c you can use `cross join` instead of `cross apply`. I don't think it would make a difference in later versions either, that just seems to be my default now...

```
select x.nm, x.ctrlsum, x.msgid
from paymentinterchange pint
cross join XMLTable(
  '//*:GrpHdr'
  passing XMLtype(pint.transportdata, nls_charset_id('AL32UTF8'))
  columns nm varchar2(50) path '//*:InitgPty/*:Nm',
    ctrlsum number path '//*:CtrlSum',
    msgid varchar2(50) path '//*:MsgId'
) x
where pint.transporttime >= date '2022-08-12'
and pint.fileformat = 'pain.001.001.03';
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=799f3ef66eed54d77c60ee40d99482ee) showing it in 11.2.0.2, where it seems to need the `//` at the start of all the paths, including in the `columns` clause - those aren't needed in later versions, but here it returns nulls without them.

Comment: Thanks, but if I run that XMLtable SQL I get an error ORA-00905: missing keyword on the 'apply'
The Nm wildcard solution works.

Comment: @Peterwarren - if you're on an older version of Oracle (before 12c) then you can use `cross join` instead of `cross apply`.

Comment: Thanks but the cross join returns no data for me:
select x.nm, x.ctrlsum, x.msgid
from bph_owner.paymentinterchange pint
cross join XMLTable(
  '//*:GrpHdr'
  passing XMLtype(pint.transportdata, nls_charset_id('AL32UTF8'))
  columns nm varchar2(50) path '*:InitgPty/*:Nm',
    ctrlsum number path '*:CtrlSum',
    msgid varchar2(50) path '*:MsgId'
) x
where pint.transporttime >= date '2022-08-12'
and pint.fileformat = 'pain.001.001.03';

Comment: Hmm. Not sure if that's a bug with wildcard handling. I'm pretty sure that worked in a patched 11gR2, but doesn't seem to in db<>fiddle's unpatched version, 11.2.0.2. Well, it returns data, but it's all nulls. It does work if you precede the `columns` paths with `//` - but you shouldn't need to, and don't in later versions. [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=799f3ef66eed54d77c60ee40d99482ee)